# Binding DataGrid Cells to an Indexed Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have created an indexed property in a class, and I need to set bindings for each cell of a `DataGridTemplateColumn` in a `DataGrid` (each cell to its corresponding item of the indexed property).

It is for a work-schedule generating application. Each cell in the grid will be displaying data relevant to an employee and shift - more employees in the shift will be growing the grid rightwards, ie adding more columns. The grid displays data structures created and filled programmatically, and not bound to a database table. For the purposes of easier presentation and code inspections in this forum, I have reduced everything to just the essentials.

Here is a pic:

[image]

This is obviously wrong, as I can't set the bindings properly. I can bind the fields in the StackPanel to the first (or any other) item of the indexed property, but not in an indexed/parameterized setting.

Here is my xaml (part of):

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <DataGrid x:Name="grdSch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,0,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="Cell"/>
</Grid>
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SPI_Template">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=shftDate}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=shftKind}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SEI_Template">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=data[0].emplName}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=data[0].shftTime}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

And the code generating the columns:

```
    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create the grid columns
        DataGridTemplateColumn col = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        col.Header = "Shift";
        col.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("SPI_Template");
        grdSch.Columns.Add(col);
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            col = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
            col.Header = "Employee " + (i + 1);
            col.Width = 100;
            col.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("SEI_Template");
            // for now show only the 5 first elements
            col.Visibility = i >= 5 ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
            grdSch.Columns.Add(col);
        }
    }
```

The `data[]` property is indexed. The bindings as they are now (eg `"{Binding Path=data[0].emplName}"`) work for the 1st item of the property. If I change it to `"{Binding Path=data[1].emplName}"` it will bind to the 2nd one and so on. But this is not what I need of course. Is there some way to change the binding to something like.... `"{Binding Path=data[Grid.ColumnIndex-1].emplName}"`? Searched and found some posts about "parameterized binding" etc, but couldn't find something quite obvious or straightforward. Of course I could go the dumb way and add 30 similar templates in the xaml (differing only in the index of the indexed property) - and this will definitely work, but I'm looking into making it in a better way.

Could someone help please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to create custom column type (deriving from `DataGridTemplateColumn`) which exposes an additional `Binding` property, which we will use to bind cell content. Here's the column code:

```
public class DataGridBoundColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
{
    public BindingBase Binding { get; set; }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var element = base.GenerateEditingElement(cell, dataItem);
        if (element != null && Binding != null)
            element.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, Binding);
        return element;
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var element = base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
        if (element != null && Binding != null)
            element.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, Binding);
        return element;
    }
}
```

Then we need to slightly modify the column generation code:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var col = new DataGridTemplateColumn
    {
        Header = "Shift",
        CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("SPI_Template")
    };
    grdSch.Columns.Add(col);
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        col = new DataGridBoundColumn
        {
            Header = "Employee " + (i + 1),
            Binding = new Binding($"data[{i}]"),
            Width = 100,
            CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("SEI_Template"),
        };
        grdSch.Columns.Add(col);
    }
}
```

Lastly, since our generated columns are already displaying `data[i]`, we need to modify the `SEI_Template` accordingly:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SEI_Template">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding emplName}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding shftDate}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Many, many Thanks! Changed the code as you suggested and it works. So, you basically bind cells directly to each item of the indexed property, instead of setting the bindings in the xaml to an indexed element. This was what I was after, but your solution works, and is therefore very much OK. Thanks again!